# What is the special name for $u_{t}=u_{xxx}$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, math-history

Is there a special name for the following type of PDE?
$$u_{t} = -u_{xxx},  \:\:\: u(x, 0) = f(x), \:\:\: t > 0$$

I found a paper mentioned that it is "linear Airy equation", but I have not found other or more than one references to substantiate that. The wikipedia mentioned differently of Airy equation: [https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Airy_equation#:~:text=The%20Airy%20equation%20is%20the,research%20in%20optics%20%5BAi%5D](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Airy_equation#:%7E:text=The%20Airy%20equation%20is%20the,research%20in%20optics%20%5BAi%5D).

Comment: Please either add the $-$ sign to the title or remove it from the body.